# Quantlib add weekends as holidays to ql.BespokeCalendar()

Tags: quantlib

Is there an easy way to add weekends to a BespokeCalendar calendar instance?

Comment: this is in python by the way

Answer (score 2):

```
o = ql.BespokeCalendar("mynewcalendar")
o.addWeekend(ql.Saturday)
o.addWeekend(ql.Sunday)
```

Comment: thank you very much!